# Visual Studio Code - python extention loading forever

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode for remote development.

I installed `Remote - SSH` extention in vscode and I connected to my server (**x**).

Once I connect to a specific folder, a message panel in vscode appears with a `python extention loading` content. The message doesn't disapear. Also I am not able to use the terminal in that moment.

[image]

A couple of things that **could** be important:

1- I use the `virtualenvwrapper` to create my virtual environments. The location of the `virtualenv` virtual environments is **not** in the default directory `$HOME/.virtualenvs`.

2- I don't connect to my home directory folder. Even when I connect to it I have the same problem. I'm mentioning this just in case there is a magical relation between the problem and the home directory.

I scanned all the web (approximately) but I didn't find a solution for this.

## Edit 1:

This is the output of the `output` panel.

```
User belongs to experiment group 'AlwaysDisplayTestExplorer - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowPlayIcon - start'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowExtensionSurveyPrompt - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'DebugAdapterFactory - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'PtvsdWheels37 - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'UseTerminalToGetActivatedEnvVars - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'AA_testing - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'WebHostNotebook - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'LocalZMQKernel - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectLSRequestTiming - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectNodeLSRequestTiming - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'EnableIPyWidgets - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'RunByLine - control'
> conda --version
> conda info --json
> pyenv root
> python3.7 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.4.76186/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
```

## Edit 2:

I tried to connect to another server (**y**). Superisingly, the issue disapear there. I just needed to configure in the settings (`python.venvPath` - Remote) the path of my virtual environments. I did the same steps with the server **x** but the issue still there. Now I can guess that the issue due to some configurations in the server (not sure).

Comment: Yes I know... I can't even understand how to run Python in VS Code

Comment: @snoopstick , there is an extention called `python`. Download it.

Comment: I know but I can't understand how to use it

Comment: @snoopstick Get a Mac

Comment: @snoopstick Save your pennies! 

Comment: What is said in the Output panel for the Python extension?

Comment: @BrettCannon , where can I find this?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface and the reference to "panel". Notice the tab strip for the panel and how one of them is named "Output". Choose that and there will be a drop-down. Change that to "Python" and there will be output from the extension about what it's doing.

Comment: @BrettCannon, I just edited the question and I added the output after choosing `python` from the drop list.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is you have `"python.jediEnabled": false` and the hold up is trying to download MPLS.

Comment: @BrettCannon , unfortunately no, it's enabled. This issue is going to make me crazy.

Comment: Do you have a bunch of conda environments? We had one other report similar to this and the person had nearly 80 conda environments created and the network traffic over SSH caused problems.

Comment: @BrettCannon, yes .. I have around 60 because this is a server and this is the way the admin configured it (shared folder). Anyway, I set before `python.pythonPath` instead of `python.venvpath`to refer directly to the compiler but nothing changed.

Comment: You have run into https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10866.

Comment: @BrettCannon yes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue of `Python extension loading` taking a long time (I don't even think it finished).

I read this issue

[Extension loads forever when there are a lot of conda environments (remote SSH)
#10866](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10866)

This led me to look at my conda environments.  I noticed `conda envs list` and `~/.conda/environments.txt` were some how out of sync (i.e. not showing the same environments.  In my case `conda envs list` had environments which were missing from  `~/.conda/environments.txt`.  I  manually added the missing environments to `~/.conda/environments.txt` and restarted VSCode.  This fixed the issue for me.

My hypothesis is that maybe VSCode was looking for environments it couldn't find or at least for some reason was getting stuck b/c somehow my conda enviroments stuff had gotten out of sync.